# Github pull request template detect YAML front matter using config.yml and apply to fields

Tags: templates, github, yaml, pull-request

I am looking to create a pull request template in GitHub where Github is able to take the YAML front matter similar to Issue_templates and parse it into the correct fields.
In Github docs under [Supported file types](https://docs.github.com/en/github/building-a-strong-community/creating-a-default-community-health-file#supported-file-types) => config.yml it claims to allow pull request template configuration.

GitHub [Docs](https://docs.github.com/en/github/building-a-strong-community/manually-creating-a-single-issue-template-for-your-repository) to Example below:

```
---
name: Name of pull request template 
about: "Use this template for setting up your PR description"
title: "Add support for the new feature"
labels: bug, enhancement, customer-request
assignees: self
---
```

The only relevant information was to pass the keys as query parameters to display one of the multiple templates, see link below.

Docs:

- [About issue and pull requests](https://docs.github.com/en/github/building-a-strong-community/about-issue-and-pull-request-templates)
- [Supported query parameters](https://docs.github.com/en/github/managing-your-work-on-github/about-automation-for-issues-and-pull-requests-with-query-parameters#supported-query-parameters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much trial and error you're not able to use a YAML front matter at this time.
The only way is to use the query parameters in the URL.

```
https://github.com/url/to/pr?
template=custom_template_pr.md
&title=Add+support+for+the+new+feature
&labels=bug%2Cenhancement%2Ccustomer-request
&assignees=self
```

Answer (score 4):

Having tested this personally, it appears that GitHub doesn't parse YAML front matter for Pull Request templates at present. You can have a single default template `pull_request_template.md`, and custom ones in `PULL_REQUEST_TEMPLATE/` accessible with the GET query `template=`. In both cases however, a front matter block will be displayed as part of the body, not parsed.

The documentation isn't very clear about this, but a `config.yml` can only be used to [configure the issue template chooser](https://docs.github.com/en/github/building-a-strong-community/configuring-issue-templates-for-your-repository#configuring-the-template-chooser). At present, there is no *pull request template chooser* to configure.

You can submit a feature request for this using the [contact support form](https://support.github.com/contact/feedback), and selecting **Pull requests and code review** for the *What part of GitHub is your feedback about?* option. That is according to [this answer](https://github.community/t/where-do-i-post-feature-requests-for-github/1501) on the community forum.

One way around this, in the meantime, might be to leave a message in your default (`pull_request_template.md`), pointing to for example, your `CONTRIBUTING.md`. Then, in that file, you could include links for each type of pull request with custom GET queries. For example, with `PULL_REQUEST_TEMPLATE/custom.md` the link might be (url broken up for convenience):

```text
https://github.com/<user>/<repo>/compare/<base>...<compare>?
template=custom.md
&title=Add+support+for+the+new+feature
&labels=bug%2Cenhancement%2Ccustomer-request
&assignees=self
```

As per the [supported query params](https://docs.github.com/en/github/managing-your-work-on-github/about-automation-for-issues-and-pull-requests-with-query-parameters#supported-query-parameters).